# SQLite does not work on android

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I tried to add SQLite to my project but when I try to run my app on emulator at the start it shows these errors and I don't have any idea about it!

```
[2012-10-25 14:16:29 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was                   forcibly closed by the remote host 
[2012-10-25 14:16:29 - Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the device.] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:395)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:462)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:109)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   [2012-10-25 14:16:30 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
```

I followed this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

my handler class:

```
 public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 // All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PHM";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_USERS = "Users";

// Users Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PASS = "password";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PASS + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}

public void addUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, user.get_name()); // User Name
    values.put(KEY_PASS, user.get_pass()); // User Phone Number

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
// Getting single User
public User getUser(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PASS }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    User user = new User(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    return user;
}

 public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> contactList = new ArrayList<User>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                User user = new User();
                user.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                user.set_name(cursor.getString(1));
                user.set_pass(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(user);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

// Getting users Count
    public int getUsersCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, user.get_name());
        values.put(KEY_PASS, user.get_pass());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_USERS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(user.get_id()) });
    }

    // Deleting single user
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_USERS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(user.get_id()) });
        db.close();
    }
}
```

This a class that I add it to my JavaScript interface by this command:

```
mean db= new mean(this, appView);
appView.addJavascriptInterface(db, "database");
```

Class:

```
 public class mean implements Cloneable{
private WebView mAppView;
private static DroidGap mGap;
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(mGap);  
  public mean(DroidGap gap, WebView view)
  {
    mAppView = view;
    mGap = gap;
  }

  public void AddUser(String name,String pass ){
        User user=new User(name,pass);
        db.addUser(user);
  }
  public String getAllUsers(){
        String ret="ajab";
        List<User> toShow=db.getAllUsers();
        for(User a :toShow){
            ret+=a.get_name();
        }
        return  ret;

  }
  public String Generate(){
      QRCodeGenerator.getQRCode ("pic.JPG", "Hamed Mahsa Pouya");
      return "BEHI";
  }
}
```

In my JavaScript I call my function like this:

```
function AddUser(name,pass){
    alert(name+"::::::"+pass);
    window.database.AddUser(name,pass);
    alert("pass");
}
```

I should mention that sometimes I saw the second alert but most of time I see this exception.

```
Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. at file:///android_asset/www/code.js:12
```

Comment: `window.database` has no method called `AddUser` in phonegap ... `window.database` is not your `DatabaseHandler` ... and tutorial that you're mention is for native app not phonegap ...

Comment: I have another class that have an Instance of DatabaseHandler...I will edit my question.

Comment: try to change `appView.addJavascriptInterface(db, "database");` to `appView.addJavascriptInterface(db, "somthingthatisnotdatabase");` and then use `window.somthingthatisnotdatabase.AddUser` in javascript and move `db = new DatabaseHandler(mGap);` to constructor `mean(DroidGap gap, WebView view)`

Comment: Still didn't work!:(
I changed it to handler.and move the one that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** This will solve the first error -Thanks Selvin for pointing it out
close eclipse
run the command "adb kill-server"
kill all running instances of the adb process
restart eclipse

Comment: i will change my -1 if you tell me what for?

Comment: because error shows you are using a dead emulator or device you need to restart it

Comment: yeah sure: Error calling method on NPObject ... the first exception is not connected to the code

Comment: Ok my bad I saw first error he pointed out which is showing ADB Connection error

Comment: I know it's not from the code that I got from there I just want to mention everything in my question.

Comment: just delete this answer :) or add to it that it will prolly fix first message :)